# Ionic Native Camera targetWidth not working

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic3 with the [ionic-native camera](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/) plugin.

I have the following:

**ts**

```
    let height: number = 720;
    let width: number = 1440;
    let options = {
        sourceType: pictureSourceType,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        quality: 50,
        targetWidth: width,
        targetHeight: height,
        correctOrientation: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        allowEdit: false
    }
    if (pictureSourceType === Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM) {
        options.correctOrientation = false;
        options.allowEdit = true;
    }
    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageURI) => {
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
            Crop.crop(imageURI, { quality: 100 }).then(newPath => {
                return this.toBase64(newPath).then((base64Img) => {
                    this.base64Image = base64Img;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
                    alert("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                });
            });
        } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
            imageURI = 'file://' + imageURI;
            Crop.crop(imageURI, { quality: 100 }).then(newPath => {
                return this.toBase64(newPath).then((base64Img) => {
                    this.base64Image = base64Img;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
                    alert("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                });
            });
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.error("CAMERA ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
        // alert("CAMERA ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    ).catch((error) => {
        console.error("ERROR getPicture -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
        alert("ERROR getPicture: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

As you can see above, the height is set to `720` and the width to `1440`. However, when I take a photo, the aspect ratio is square, i.e. it is the same height as width.

I think the issue may be related to the [`Crop`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/crop/).

Please can anyone advise how to set the aspect ratio?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you first get the image from the camera and then Crop is creating a square of it.

Comment: Yes, I crop it to a square. But I want a rectangle. width > height

Comment: It's how crop works, if you don't want a square don't crop it or look for another plugin that doesn't crop as a square. Looking a crop, it looks like it only creates the square on Android, it seems that on iOS you can resize the box as you wish